# Default location of freepbx backup?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I am using Asterisk 11 with Freepbx 2.11.0.43. I generated a backup using backup&restore module. Where is the default location of backup file?

Answer (score 3):

In current versions of FreePBX, backups are stored in `__ASTSPOOLDIR__/backup/`, listed as the "Local Storage" location. In most systems `__ASTSPOOLDIR__` is located at `/var/spool/asterisk/`.

Prior to FreePBX 2.10 backups were stored in `__ASTVARLIBDIR__/backups/`. This location is referred to as the "Legacy Backup" location in current versions. Backup definitions created in an older version of FreePBX will use this location after an upgrade to version 2.10+.

Answer (score 0):

Not in all system it will be that location

Simplest way find on any system do

```
find / -name 'backup*z'
```